# How to declare alia shorthands of methods of my custom JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects, alias, declare

I wonder how I could create alias shorthands for methods in my JavaScript library...

My library's method declaration is structured like this:

```
myLib = function(selector){

  var x, obj = {

   slct(selector){
    // ... the method itself ...
   },

   attr(a,b){
    if(x){
      // ... the method itself ...
      return this
    }
   },

   class(a,b){
     if(x){
       // ... the method itself ...
       return this
     }
   },

   data(a,b){
    if(x){
      // ... the method itself ...
      return this
    }
   },

   style(a,b){
      if(x){
        // ... the method itself ...
        return this
      }
    }

    // ... and many more ...

  };
  x = obj.slct(selector);
  return obj
}
```

I call my methods like this:

```
myLib('#someDOMelement').attr('href','https://domain.tld/subpage');
myLib('#someDOMelement').class('someNewClass');
myLib('#someDOMelement').data('someDataSet');
myLib('#someDOMelement').style('background','#000');
```

But I would like to declare aliases of my methods like for example:

```
myLib('#someDOMelement').a('href','https://domain.tld/subpage');
myLib('#someDOMelement').c('someNewClass');
myLib('#someDOMelement').d('someDataSet');
myLib('#someDOMelement').s('background','#000');
```

How could I do this?

The only way I am seeing right now is to declare the whole method 2nd time which won't be the most efficient way I guess. :D

Thanks for any help about this! :)

Comment: You should use a prototype, then you could assign `myLib.prototype.a = myLib.prototype.attr`. There's no easy way to do it if the methods are in each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating the object for each call to `myLib` and relying on the fact that the functions close over `x`, there's no real shortcut (no pun intended) other than one involving accessors (further down in the answer), you just have to set up those properties after creating `obj`:

```
  // ...
  obj.a = obj.attr;
  obj.c = obj.class;
  obj.d = obj.data;
  obj.s = obj.slct;
  x = obj.slct(selector);
  return obj
}
```

or you could use a loop, but it seems less maintainable:

```
  // ...
  for (const name of ["attr", "class", "data", "slct"]) {
      obj[name.charAt(0)] = obj[name];
  }
  x = obj.slct(selector);
  return obj
}
```

Another way would be to use a prototype with accessor properties for `a` etc., but it adds another function call (not that that usually matters):

```
const myLibProto = {
    get a() {
        return this.attr;
    },
    get c() {
        return this.class;
    },
    get d() {
        return this.data;
    },
    get s() {
        return this.slct;
    }
};
myLib = function(selector){

  var x, obj = Object.assign(Object.create(myLibProto), {

   slct(selector){
    // ... the method itself ...
   },

   attr(a,b){
    if(x){
      // ... the method itself ...
      return this
    }
   },

   class(a,b){
     if(x){
       // ... the method itself ...
       return this
     }
   },

   data(a,b){
    if(x){
      // ... the method itself ...
      return this
    }
   },

   style(a,b){
      if(x){
        // ... the method itself ...
        return this
      }
    }

    // ... and many more ...

  }));
  x = obj.slct(selector);
  return obj
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! your answer really helped me a lot about this whole topic! :)